# Using \footnotesize in underbrace

Tags: fontsize, underbrace

I want to use `\footnotesize*` in an underbrace text.
My code is:

```
\underbrace{x(t+\Delta t)V-x(t)V}_{ \footnotesize{\text{Change of \# of X molecules}}} 
&=-\underbrace{c}_{\footnotesize \substack{\text{\# of the reaction} \\ \text{per unit time}}} \cdot 
\underbrace{\binom{x(t)V}{a}}_{\footnotesize \substack{\text{choosing $a$ molecules}\\ \text{from $x(t)V$ of them}}} \cdot 
\underbrace{\binom{y(t)V}{b}}_{\footnotesize \substack{\text{choosing $b$ molecules}\\ \text{from $y(t)V$ of them}}} \cdot \Delta t
```

and it shows

[image]

I can check that `\footnotesize` is applied to the `\substack` environment, but not to the normal text in underbrace.
How can I make this text smaller?
Could you help me?

Comment: `\footnotesize` has to occur inside the `\text` wrappers

Comment: The default font size for material below the underbrace is `\scriptsize`. Are you sure you want to *increase* the font size, relative to what TeX does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\footnotesize`, along with `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\small`, etc are text-mode, not a math-mode, macros. If you want to employ `footnotesize` instead of the default `\scriptsize`, you need issue this instruction *inside* the `\text` wrappers. Yep, all 7 instances of `\text`.

Actually, I would have thought you were looking *decrease* the font size further, to `\tiny`, rather than to increase it to `\footnotesize`.

Separately, do also look into aligning the underbraces across all four underbraces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \underbrace macro
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{x(t+\Delta t)V-x(t)V\vphantom{\bigg(}}_{%
             \text{\tiny Change of \# of $X$ molecules}} 
=
-{\underbrace{c\vphantom{\bigg(}}_{%
   \substack{\text{\tiny \# of reactions} \\ 
             \text{\tiny per unit of time}}}} 
\cdot 
{\underbrace{\binom{x(t)V}{a}}_{%
   \substack{\text{\tiny choosing $a$ molecules}\\ 
             \text{\tiny from $x(t)V$ of them}}}} 
\cdot 
{\underbrace{\binom{y(t)V}{b}}_{%
   \substack{\text{\tiny choosing $b$ molecules}\\ 
             \text{\tiny from $y(t)V$ of them}}}}
\cdot 
\Delta t
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works well.